# Unexpected text being rendered by Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have models

```
// models/group
export default DS.Model.extend({
    parent: DS.belongsTo('parent'),
    items: DS.hasMany('item', {async: true}),

    quantity: Ember.computed.sum('items.@each.quantity'),

});

// models/item
export default DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    quantity: DS.attr('number')
});
```

And in my template (with `controller.model` set to `parent`) I try to render

```
{{#each group}}
    {{quantity}}
{{/each}}
```

and expect a list of numbers, but instead what's rendered is a list of text like `<spa@model:item::ember1036:165>`

I'm guessing that the async promise is only resolved after rendering, but then why does it not update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe sum will pull properties from each item in a collection.  I believe it has to be a collection of numbers.

```
quantities: function(){
   return this.get('items').getEach('quantity');
}.property('items.@each.quantity'),

quantity: Ember.computed.sum('quantities'),
```

Comment: You are right: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.7.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/computed/reduce_computed_macros.js#L29

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that `quantities` can also be expressed as `quantities: Ember.computed.mapBy('items', 'quantity')`?